# Post request is not working in my servlet but get request does

Tags: tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I have created a servlet that is capable of responding to both get and post requests.
The problem is that when I am sending a post request using a form I get no response.
Here is the code.

XmlServlet.java :

```
package org.skiabox.myservlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String fullName = request.getParameter("fullName");
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        out.println("Hello from POST method " + userName + "! We know your full name is " + fullName);

        String prof = request.getParameter("prof");
        out.println("<br/>" + "You are a " + prof);

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        out.println("Hello " + userName);
    }
}
```

---

SimpleForm.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/XmlServletPath">
        User Name:<input name="userName"/>
        Full Name:<input name="fullName"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Profession:
        <input type="radio" name="prof" value="Developer">Developer</input>
        <input type="radio" name="prof" value="Architect">Architect</input>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <description>A simple servlet</description>
        <display-name>SimpleServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.skiabox.myservlet.SimpleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>XmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.skiabox.myservlet.XmlServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SimpleServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/XmlServletPath</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

SimpleServletProject.iml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="web" name="Web">
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <deploymentDescriptor name="web.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
        </descriptors>
        <webroots>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web" relative="/" />
        </webroots>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Tomcat 7.0" level="application_server_libraries" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Tomcat settings :
[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Page to enter details url : `http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleForm.html`

Result page (completely empty) url after pressing submit : `http://localhost:8080/XmlServletPath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your servlet is listening on `http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/XmlServletPath`, not on `http://localhost:8080/XmlServletPath`. Your form was submitting to the wrong URL.

Just fix the form action URL accordingly. Replace

```
<form method="post" action="/XmlServletPath">
```

by

```
<form method="post" action="/SimpleServletProject/XmlServletPath">
```

or, if the page presenting the form is in the same URL folder anyway

```
<form method="post" action="XmlServletPath">
```

or, if you worry about the dynamicness of the context path

```
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/XmlServletPath">
```

Comment: This was the first thing that I tried but it failed.Now that I am trying it again it works.Maybe I typed something wrong.Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: In fact I am following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnUJl3NYRRc&list=PLE0F6C1917A427E96) and this guy manages the same result by using the simple /XmlServletPath as an action parameter and not the full path, but he uses another ide (Eclipse).

Comment: That will (obviously) only work if the webapp is deployed to context root (in your case, when you've `/` instead of `/SimpleServletProject`). The latter two lines in my answer should still work regardless of the context path and makes your webapp thus more portable.

Comment: It may be a trick of Eclipse, that presents the root context as `http://localhost/SimpleServletProject` because if I want to use XmlServletPath alone in the action parameter I must set my root context to `/` (with IntelliJ Idea).

Comment: No. A project which is deployed to context root is available on `http://localhost` only.

Comment: If you watch the video you'll see it.He uses a simple 'XmlServletPath' as an action parameter in the form and when he press submit he has a response at the following url (http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/XmlServletPath)

Comment: I didn't and won't watch the video, but the `action="XmlServletPath"` is already covered by my answer. Please note that this is not the same as `action="/XmlServletPath"` which you initially used and mentioned in a previous comment.